# Test Lazy<object> is getting NullException

Tags: c#, asp.net, api, unit-testing, nunit

So, I am trying to test an API method using Nunit, but when the API reaches the lazy object it returns a NullObjectException.
So far the only way that I find to solve it was changing the object to public and initializing it, but that's not the better approach, does anyone can help me?

`private Lazy<Versions> _versions;`

```
void OnStart()
{
...
    _versions = new Lazy<Versions>(() => CurrentSystem.GetVersions());
}
```

```
AccountResponse Account()
{
...
    version = _versions.Value
}
```

Comment: Why not `private readonly Lazy<Versions> _versions = new Lazy<Versions>(() => CurrentSystem.GetVersions())` (this field will now be assigned when a new instance is created)? Variables have to be assigned before they will be something other than the default value. As Lazy is a reference type, the default value will be null, and this has nothing particularly to do with Lazy at all!

Comment: It is unclear how "public" or "unit testing" fits in the current question; that said, _it will probably aid unit testing_ if passing a `Func<Versions>` _as a constructor dependency_ and letting the constructor turn that into a Lazy. This is standard dependency injection, and again unrelated to Lazy.

Comment: To do it the CurrentSystem would have to be static

Comment: @user2864740 My test is failing because when it tries to use the lazy variable it gets a null exception

Comment: It has nothing to do with Lazy. This is standard failure to assign a field before use. As per above, ensure it is properly initialized (ie. during object creation) or specified explicitly as a dependency. Or if OnStart must be called to setup the test state, call that first. Might as well be `private string _foo; /* not assigned before use */ .. Console.WriteLite(_foo.Length); /* NullReferenceException during use */` later.

Comment: You gave me some ideas to try it from a different approach, that's my first time using lazy, but I will give it a shot